# Upgrade gitlab from 12.10.3 to 14.1

Tags: gitlab

I have a self hosted gitlab-ce in a docker environment.

As upgrading GitLab is a pain, I did not do it for a while and now it looks way too complex.
Also there are no good material on how to do this step wise.

Has anyone done this before: what process are you following?

Answer (score 0):

The main advice from the [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/) is to avoid skiping a major version.

In your case, upgrade first to 13.11.
Then 14.1.0.

That way, you can detect any specific setting to update fro one version to the next.